# how to fix an error about pytorch aotugrad mechanism?

Tags: python

trans=transforms.ToTensor()
#load datasets   mnist_train=torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root="../data",train=True,transform=trans,download=True)
mnist_test=torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root="../data",train=False,transform=trans,download=True)

```
def softmax(x,w,b):
    out=torch.matmul(x,w)+b
    out_exp=torch.exp(out)
    pos=out_exp/out_exp.sum(axis=1,keepdim=True)
    return pos
def loss(pos,y):
    row=list(range(len(y)))
    indices= zip( list(range(len(y))),y)
    y_possi=[-torch.log(pos[i])for i in indices]
    loss=torch.tensor(y_possi,dtype=torch.float32)
    return loss
```

```
def accuracy(pos,y):
    y_hat=pos.argmax(axis=1)
    return (y_hat==y).sum(),len(y)
class Accumulator:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.data=[0]*n
    def add(self,*args):
        for index,arg in enumerate(*args):
            self.data[index]+=float(arg)
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.data[index]        
def sgd(params,lr,batch_size):
    with torch.no_grad():
        for param in params:
            param-= lr * param.grad /batch_size
            param.grad.zero_()
#main function
epochs=6
num_inputs=28*28
num_outputs=10
batch_size=256
W=torch.normal(0,0.01,(num_inputs,num_outputs)).requires_grad_()
b=torch.zeros(size=(1,num_outputs)).requires_grad_()
train_iter=data.DataLoader(mnist_train,batch_size=256,shuffle=True)
test_iter=data.DataLoader(mnist_test,batch_size=256,shuffle=True)
def train(data_iter,lr,w,b,epochs,batch_size):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        metrics=Accumulator(3)
        for x,y in data_iter:
            x=x.reshape(-1,28*28)
            pos=softmax(x,w,b)
            los=loss(pos,y)
            los.sum().backward()
            sgd([w,b],lr,batch_size)
            metrics.add(los,accuracy(pos,y))
        with torch.no_grad():
            print(f'epoch:{epoch+1},loss:{metrics[0]},accuracy:{float(metrics[1]/metrics[2])}')
train(train_iter,0.03,W,b,epochs,batch_size)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Comment: los.sum().backward()